# How To Loop Through Messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

I am getting pretty stuck and have been looking through the documentation but nothing is jumping out at me clearly.
**What I am trying to do is, have my bot load the messages over a specified range, and count the occurrences of a specific defined phrase.**

*ex.
phrase = "wagons"
!phrase 5 - returns all the messages in the last 5 days
and then returns the amount of times "wagons" has been said in the last 5 days*

```
""" Simple program for the bot to return information about the guild """
import os
import datetime as dt
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # loads the encapsulated values from the .env file

# Declaration of Encapsulated Variables
TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
TESTING_GUILD_KEY = os.getenv('TESTING_GUILD_KEY')
TESTING_CHANNEL = os.getenv('TESTING_CHANNEL')

# Declaration of Discord.py Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Turns on the connection
intents.members = True  # Ensures the member list will be updated properly
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)  # captures the connection to discord

# Declaration of Discord.py Variables
guild_key = client.get_guild(int(TESTING_GUILD_KEY))
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    """ Defines events for which the bot will return information by the user typing commands """
    all_members = get_all_members()  # has all the members visible to the bot

    # Sends to the channel the event is called, the total amount of users in the guild
    if message.content.find("!userCount") != -1:
        await message.channel.send(f"""We currently have {len(all_members)} members in the server""")
    # Sends to the channel the event is called, a list of users currently in the guild
    elif message.content.startswith('!member'):
        await message.channel.send(f"""The current member list is: \n""")
        for each_member in all_members:
            await message.channel.send(f"""- {each_member}""")


def get_all_members():
    """ Returns A list of users currently in the server """
    list_of_members = []  # Declaration of Empty Dictionary

    # Declaration of logic to print out each user in the guild
    for each_guild in client.guilds:
        for each_member in each_guild.members:
            list_of_members.append(each_member)  # adds the member
    return list_of_members


# @client.event
# async def keyword(ctx, word):
#     channel = client.get_channel(int(TESTING_CHANNEL))
#     messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
#     count = 0
#
#     for msg in messages:
#         if word in msg.content:
#             count += 1
#             print(count)


@bot.command()
async def something(ctx):
    pass


@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, days: int = None, phrase: str = None):
    if days and phrase:
        after_date = dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(days=days)
        # limit can be changed to None but that this would make it a slow operation.
        messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=10, oldest_first=True, after=after_date).flatten()
        # loop each message to check for phrase
        for message in messages:
            if phrase in message.content:
                print(message)
    else:
        await ctx.send("please enter the number of days wanted")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I think I am close using the phrase function, however, it is not working properly. Not sure if I have to turn intents on, or if there is something I am missing from the code.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `discord.ext.commands`. Please read [this example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) for a sample bot taken from the docs.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def something(ctx):
    pass

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

You make a command with an `int` argument called `days` then take the timedelta from the time the command invoked.

Also check each message if it has the `phrase` in it.

- `!find 4 long text to check` prints all the message for the last 4 days with the phrase.
- `!find 14 long text to check` prints all the message for the last 14 days with the phrase.

```py
# import datatime as dt

@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, days: int = None, *, phrase:str = None):
    if not (days or phrase):
        return await ctx.send("Please enter a phrase and days")
        
    if days and phrase:
        after_date = dt.datetime.utcnow()-dt.timedelta(days=days)
        # limit can be changed to None but that this would make it a slow operation.
        messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=10, oldest_first=True, after=after_date).flatten()
        # loop each message to check for phrase
        for message in messages:
            if phrase in message.content:
                print(message)
    else:
        await ctx.send("please enter the number of days wanted")
```

[`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel.history#discord.TextChannel.history)

> Returns an AsyncIterator that enables receiving the destination’s message history. You must have read_message_history permissions to use this.

**UPDATE:**

Please read this [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands)

Also change the following:

- `@client.event` to `@bot.event`
- `client.run(TOKEN)` to `bot.run(TOKEN)`
- Remove `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` since `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)` would take place for it

I also edited the code above to include the history with no phrase to be defaulted.

Comment: My bot doesn't seem to do anything when I type the example you provided. I updated my code above

Comment: Taken from the `TextChannel.history` `You must have read_message_history permissions to use this.`

Comment: Make sure you run `bot` and change all `client` to `bot`

Comment: _right click on channel_ > _Edit Channel_ > _Premissions_  > Green Checkmark on **Read Message History** is that right? 
I done that. It still doesn't appear to work, also calling !find with no time parameter doesn't print anything to console either.

Also, thank you so much for your time and help. I am greatly appreciating this.